# Can I generate a skewed ellipse tangent to two points?

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

I'm trying to write a python script to generate a trailing edge (TE)  for [an airfoil with no TE](http://airfoiltools.com/airfoil/details?airfoil=ah93w257-il). Basically want to make a smooth round-off nose profile to the right, the closure line should come out smoothly to a single point. With simpler airfoils it's fairly easy to generate a circle and finish the TE with that arc, however this one is irregular.

I'm thinking a good way to do this would be:

- Find mean line between upper and lower surface (known as a camber line), and use this function to generate a trailing edge point a little past the end of the given points
- Generate some sort of skewed ellipse that passes through this point and the final point on both the upper and lower sides of the airfoil, as well as matching the tangency at these points

Is there a simple way of doing something like this? Geometry is not one of my strong points.

This better illustrates the irregularity at the trailing edge:

[image: Trailing Edge]